# Program independent of its path

Tags: linux

How do developers usually deal with different paths for executable files?

My program is currently in /usr/local/bin and I am wondering how to make it work weather it is in /usr/local/bin or in /usr/bin while being able to access the config files from one of the etc folders (depends on the executable path).

I can't just use relative paths because I need to make it relative to the path of the executable file and even then, it wouldn't be enough because I would need to access /etc weather than /usr/local/etc.

Is there a common way to deal with this situation? Is it dealt with during the installation? Do I need to make a different version of my program for the local and for the global path?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Obviously you can't (and shouldn't) use relative paths, as you say in your question. So, the answer is: Use absolute paths. The location of `/etc` doesn't change depending on the location of your binary.

Comment: I meant that in case 1 (/usr/local/bin), I need to access /usr/local/etc and in case 2 (/usr/bin), I need to access /usr.

Comment: This is usually handled by compile-time configuration with macros that get their value from the `makefile`.

Comment: E.g. `make CONFIGDIR=/usr/local/etc`

Answer (score 1):

In a shell script, you can detect the executable path of the script with

```
dirname `readlink -f $0`
```

and work with that.

Comment: I said that getting the executable path would not be enough because if I understand it correctly, if I the executable is in /usr/local/bin, I need to access /usr/local/etc (= executable/../etc) and if the executable is in /usr/bin, I need to access /etc (=executable/../../etc).

Comment: If your programming language has an `if` statement, you can check the executable path and decide which path to use for your configuration files. If the path is /usr/bin, use /etc. If it is /usr/local/bin, use /usr/local/etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your program as root, then it should be able to access the configuration files on /etc/ or any other place without a problem. You could `grep` it from the script or whatever you need.

If your program is not run as root, then you should make sure that the configuration file being accessed on /etc/ gives the user the right to read it. See [chmod man](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) for more information.

Finally, your script should run fine from any of the locations you mentioned, although `/usr/local/bin/` is generally where locally developed scripts should go. Just call your script by its full path and it will work: ex:  `/usr/local/bin/script`

Note: don't forget to make your script executable: `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/script`

Comment: My issue was not about the chmod permissions, but about finding my config files no matter where my script is. You said that I could use grep to search for my config file, do you know if this is something that is usually done ? That sounds overkill to me but I don't know much either

Comment: The place where your script is stored should not matter -- as long as you run it as root or have the right permissions, you should be able to retrieve the configuration files with no problem, just use the full path for the configuration file like `/etc/myscript/conf`.

Comment: but if I decide to change its path from /etc/myscript/conf to /usr/local/etc/myscript/conf, I will need to change all the full paths used in the script, right ?

Comment: as a consequence, the users can't choose where they want to install my script

Comment: Ok, this is new information not specified on your question (the user choosing where to install your script). Nonetheless, you can have your script to install the conf file on the same place always, no matter where the script is installed (you specify that during installation). But normally, programs have a "master" conf file and a "user" conf file, which is normally stored on `/home/user/.somewhere` -- this way the user can change configurations for his own use independently of what configurations other users have.